# os.fork exit the script if the child fails to run command

Tags: python

I am a novice in python trying to use multi-process with fork. What I wanted to do is to run a command on few hosts. I am able to do with the below code but I also want to stop execution if any of the child fails to run the command or the command itself fails.

```
def runCommand(host,comp):
    if os.system("ssh "+host+" 'somecommand'") != 0:
            print "somecommand failed on "+host+" for "+comp
            sys.exit(-1)

def runMulti():
    children = []
    for comp,host in conHosts.iteritems():
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid:
                    children.append(pid)
            else:
                    sleep(5)
                    runCommand(host,comp)
                    os._exit(0)

    for i, child in enumerate(children):
            os.waitpid(child, 0)
```

Comment: if the code works, then why ask?

Comment: this might be better on code review.se

Comment: your indentation is weird

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC This code does not work as intended: "[..] but I also want to stop execution if any of the child fails [..]". As such it would be off-topic for CR.SE

Comment: @Sumurai8 misread it, thought it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using ThreadPool.

```
    pool = ThreadPool(len(hosts))
    try:
            pool.map(runMulti(), 'True')
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
    except:
            os.system('touch /tmp/failed')
            commands.getoutput("killall -q ssh")
            os.kill(os.getpid(),9)
```

I have created a temp file, when a thread in the pool exists with different status.Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the return value of [`waitpid`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.waitpid) and see if the child process exited with a status different from `0`:

```
had_error = any(os.waitpid(child, 0)[1] for child in children)
if had_error:
    sys.exit(1)
```

---

Note: since you are checking the return value of `os.fork` the list `children` will be empty in the child processes and so `any` will always return `False`, i.e. only the master process will eventually call `sys.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

`os.fork()` returns `0` in the child process. So you can do:

```
if not os.fork():
    # we now know we're the child process
    execute_the_work()
    if failed:
        sys.exit()
```

`sys.exit()` is the pythonic way to exit a python program. Don't forget to `import sys`.

Since you seem to be a beginner, replace `failed` with the condition to judge if the task failed.

Comment: Note that the documentation of [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os._exit) state: "**Note** The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n)` . **`_exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a `fork()`.** " In other words the code of the OP is perfectly fine.